# How to sort range values in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting

Below is part of a range in dataframe that I work withI have tried to sort it using df.sort_values(['column']) but it doesn't work. I would appreciate advice.

[image]

Comment: the column has two values (min, max) how do you want it sorted?

Comment: I think the answer below is correct as It has solved my smilar problem. Altough not obligated but it would be kind of you to accept it as the accepted answer(clicking check mark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify solution for sorting by values before `-` converting to integers in parameter `key`:

```
f = lambda x: x.str.split('-').str[0].str.replace(',','', regex=True).astype(int)
df = df.sort_values('column', key= f, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
             column
0       1,000-1,999
1       2,000-2,949
2       3,000-3,999
3       4,000-4,999
4       5,000-7,499
5     10,000-14,999
6     15,000-19,999
7     20,000-24,999
8     25,000-29,999
9     30,000-39,999
10    40,000-49,999
11  103,000-124,999
12  125,000-149,999
13  150,000-199,999
14  200,000-249,999
15  250,000-299,999
16  300,000-499,999
```

Another idea is use first integers for sorting:

```
f = lambda x: x.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
df = df.sort_values('column', key= f, ignore_index=True)
```

If need sorting by both values splitted by `-` it is possible by:

```
f = lambda x: x.str.replace(',','', regex=True).str.extract('(\d+)-(\d+)', expand=True).astype(int).apply(tuple, 1)
df = df.sort_values('column', key= f, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it has helped me as well :)